# How to regenerate missing WordPress thumbnails?

Tags: wordpress, thumbnails

This is the problem on my site.

Suddenly 5000 thumbnails disappeared from my server. The files are not there.
Most of them are from 1 of 2 sizes: either 0x550 or 550x0.
I've tried regenerating them with the available plugins (AJAX Thumbnail rebuild, etc). Almost 3000 were created with the right size.

That leaves me with 2k images missing.
Here's the thing.

If I edit a post that contains the embeded image, and click the "edit" button on the image itself -which obviously doesn't show but an error square takes it place-, when the lightbox shows up, the image is then re-created at the right size.

So, since all the plugins failed the only option now is to recreate each image by editing it on the post itself.

I already have the URLS of the missing images thanks to a 404 error checking plugin.

**So basically I can take the URLs and extract the original image name and width/height from there. But how can I manually create the thumbnail file using that information?**

Thanks for your help!